# How can I plot a graph of a function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph this function

```
=1/4cos**2(θA0 − θB0) + cos**2(θA0 − θB1)+cos**2(θA1 − θB0) + sin**2(θA1 − θB1)
```

this is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

b = np.arange(0, 1, 0)
d = np.arange(0, 1, 0)

B, D = np.meshgrid(A0, B0)
nu = =1/4cos**2(θA0 − θB0) + cos**2(θA0 − θB1)+cos**2(θA1 − θB0) + sin**2(θA1 − θB1)



fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(A0, B0, nu)
plt.xlabel('A0')
plt.ylabel('B0')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the problem/issue you are facing?

Comment: Your formula is non-sensical. What is `A0`, what is `θB1`, what is `cos**2()`? I suggest getting first familiar with [basic Python operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm) and [mathematical numpy functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html)

Comment: `nu = =...` cannot work. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import the math library to use the cosine and sine functions. So, you have to define all your constants and save the "nu" function value one at a time.

I assume A0 and B0 are constant, so you can represent your function in a 2D chart. In this case, the code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

# parameters
a0 = 1
a1 = 2
b0 = 3
b1 = 4
t = np.linspace(-(2 * np.pi), 2 * np.pi, 200)  # theta

# formula
nu = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    nu.append(1/4 * math.cos(t[i]*a0 - t[i]*b0)**2 + math.cos(t[i]*a0 - t[i]*b1)**2 + 
              math.cos(t[i]*a1 - t[i]*b0)**2 + math.sin(t[i]*a1 - t[i]*b1)**2)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, nu, color='red', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('a0')
plt.ylabel('b0')
plt.show()
```

Otherwise, you can modify A0 and B0 similar to theta and implement a 3D graph.

Comment: This is, even given the unclear question, simply wrong. The OP wants to plot a 3D surface, so the initial idea of using `np.meshgrid` is good. And mixing math functions with numpy arrays will ultimately fail.